# Clear user profile (remove new files/folders/changes) on every logout/machine startup

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I clear Windows 10 local user profile (remove all new files/folders/changes) on every logout/machine startup? I prefer PowerShell script, but any other ways also could by good.

Any Idea how to do that?
This is public located computer (public library).

Comment: your efforts so far?

Comment: Make the account a guest account. Questions like this belong on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for something similar as well. I have found several different things, like is this on a network? Are you looking to remove the profile or just delete changes? Which version of 10 are you running- Pro, Enterprise or Education?

I don't know too much about trying to use powershell for this, but there are many solutions out there depending on needs. Enterprise and Education versions have embedded write filters which remove changes on restarts. For Pro versions you could use a software like Deep Freeze (paid), Time Freeze (free) or Reboot Restore (both paid and free). However, those are changes on restarts only and could cause issues with antivirus and also Windows updates. Reboot Restore has a paid version, but it only restarts the pc after logoff which could be done while running "shutdown /f /r /t 0" in a log off script, and accomplish the same thing.

As for removing changes when logging off only, and not only on restarting, you could try using a mandatory profile. The process is fairly simple, but it requires a network share. At least I haven't been able to get it to work right with redirecting it to a local path. I have not tried using guest accounts on 10 because I have read how it does not work correctly, even when enabling the account which is not the problem. That doesn't mean not to try it, I just haven't.

We have about 35 locations over a WAN with ~4 computers at each location. So I decided to go with Clean Slate Complete by Fortres Grand. They offer an online ability with many really cool features. I have noticed that there are some quirks about it, but as far as setting restrictions for removing all changes at logoff it seems to work rather well. I am sure that you could find what those changes are and see about making them yourself and save the money. They do offer a free trial too, so it's worth a look.